# Move Navigation Bar Text Left in MVC Default Project

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created an MVC Net Core Project Default Project. I set everything up models, controllers and  displaying items in a page list.I am trying to locate the CSS html location, so I can move the following text left.

Apparently site.css edit, will make the titles bold but will not move titles left.

```
.navbar-nav {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to use `float: left`. The `text-align: left` will move the content left but inside the container.

Comment: yeah, tried that, still not working-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also reset the `margin-left` rules defined by `.container` . See the default `margin-left` of `.container` inside the `.navbar-fixed-top`:

Right click on Area in Google Chrome, and do click Inspect.

[image]

So adding a rule of `margin-left :0`  will work :

```
.navbar-fixed-top >.container {
    margin-left:0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
```

[image]